# How to use a custom CRS in PROJ?

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, proj, geodjango

I want to change the CRS of a shapefile which uses [EPSG:6257](http://epsg.io/6257). Unfortunately, I am using Ubuntu 20.04 which comes with [PROJ6](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/proj-bin). This particular CRS was only made available [from PROJ7.2 onwards](https://proj.org/operations/projections/col_urban.html). So, I am now exploring my options to use a custom CRS in Proj. According to the [documentation](https://proj.org/faq.html#coordinate-reference-system-xyz-is-not-in-the-epsg-registry-what-do-i-do):

> #### Coordinate reference system xyz is not in the EPSG registry, what do I do?
>
> Generally PROJ will accept coordinate reference system descriptions in
> the form of WKT, WKT2 and PROJ strings. If you are able to describe
> your desired CRS in either of those formats there’s a good chance that
> PROJ will be able to make sense of it.

So, I have been trying to do just that, but I struggle to make this work. I'm using Django's geodjango library, where I can use [SpatialReference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/gis/gdal/#spatialreference) to set a CRS. According to that documentation:

> #### class SpatialReference(srs_input)¶
>
> ```
> Spatial reference objects are initialized on the given srs_input, which may be one of the following:
>
>     - OGC Well Known Text (WKT) (a string)
>     - EPSG code (integer or string)
>     - PROJ string
>     - A shorthand string for well-known standards ('WGS84', 'WGS72', 'NAD27', 'NAD83')
> ```

So I have been trying to set this in a number of ways, but nothing works.

If I use the "WKT Version 2" from the [EPSG website](https://epsg.org/crs/wkt/id/6257):

```
crs = 'PROJCRS["MAGNA-SIRGAS / Medellin urban grid",BASEGEOGCRS["MAGNA-SIRGAS",DATUM["Marco Geocentrico Nacional de Referencia",ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,ID["EPSG",9001]],ID["EPSG",7019]],ID["EPSG",6686]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,ANGLEUNIT["radian",1,ID["EPSG",9101]],ID["EPSG",8901]],ID["EPSG",4686]],CONVERSION["Medellin urban grid",METHOD["Colombia Urban",ID["EPSG",1052]],PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",6.229208889,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,ID["EPSG",9102]]],PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",-75.564886944,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,ID["EPSG",9102]]],PARAMETER["False easting",835378.647,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,ID["EPSG",9001]]],PARAMETER["False northing",1180816.875,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,ID["EPSG",9001]]],PARAMETER["Projection plane origin height",1510,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,ID["EPSG",9001]]],ID["EPSG",6225]],CS[Cartesian,2,ID["EPSG",4500]],AXIS["Northing (N)",north],AXIS["Easting (E)",east],LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,ID["EPSG",9001]],USAGE[SCOPE["Cadastre, engineering survey, topographic mapping (large scale)."],AREA["Colombia - Medellin city."],BBOX[6.12,-75.66,6.37,-75.50]],ID["EPSG",6257]]'

ct = CoordTransform(SpatialReference(medellin), SpatialReference("WGS84"))
```

Then I get:

> django.contrib.gis.gdal.error.GDALException: Corrupt data.

```
medellin = 'GEOGCRS["MAGNA-SIRGAS",DATUM["Marco Geocentrico Nacional de Referencia",ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,ID["EPSG",9001]],ID["EPSG",7019]],ID["EPSG",6686]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,ANGLEUNIT["radian",1,ID["EPSG",9101]],ID["EPSG",8901]],ID["EPSG",4686]]'
ct = CoordTransform(SpatialReference(medellin), SpatialReference("WGS84"))
```

Returns the same:

> django.contrib.gis.gdal.error.GDALException: Corrupt data.

Trying another format from the shapefile itself:

```
medellin = """GEOGCS["GCS_MAGNA",
    DATUM["Marco_Geocentrico_Nacional_de_Referencia",
        SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
    UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]"""
```

> Unsupported SRS.

Any idea how I can use this custom CRS that is not present in my version of PROJ?

Comment: If you just want a one-time transformation, you could consider using a Docker container with Proj 7 or 8: https://hub.docker.com/r/osgeo/proj/tags?page=1&ordering=last_updated

Comment: Thanks but I need to do this on the fly with new files coming in as well.